# Dificuldade na metodologia de programação e migração do mysqli para o PDO

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, pessoal.

Sempre programei na parte do Back-End (com PHP) utilizando o mysqli, porém após ler alguns artigos e comentários, cheguei a conclusão que preciso mudar minha método de programar para o PDO (Por motivos de Segurança e organização dos códigos) e futuramente passar a utilizar o paradigma de Orientação à Objetos, ao invés do meu já tradicional padrão estruturado.

**Minha dúvida é a seguinte, sempre fiz o código com mysqli da forma abaixo:**

```html
<?php

  //SELECT QUE RETORNA OS DADOS PARA O AJAX
    $select_empresas = "SELECT * from tbl_lista_empresas order by EMPRESA";
    $lista_empresas = mysqli_query($conecta, $select_empresas);
      
    if(!$lista_empresas)
    {
     die("Erro no Banco - Erro no Select na tabela lista_empresas");
     exit;
    }
    
    
    $retorno_empresas = array();
    //PASSANDO OS DADOS DO SELECT PARA UM ARRAY
    while($linha_empresas = mysqli_fetch_object($lista_empresas))
    {     
     $retorno_empresas[] = $linha_empresas;     
    }
        
        echo json_encode($retorno_empresas); 



?>
```

- Geralmente recebo uma requisição do AJAX, e (quase sempre é desse mesma forma), realizo uma consulta no PHP com mysqli, passo o resultado da consulta para um ARRAY e retorno o resultado da consulta para o AJAX no formato JSON.

**E assim eu recebo os dados no AJAX**

```js
//Função que faz a alteração dos dados do funcionário
function alterar_empresas(alterarempresas) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../banco/banco-sistema/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/alterar-empresas.php",
    type: "post",
    data: alterarempresas.serialize(),
    cache: false

  }).done(function(retornoempresas) {
    $.each($.parseJSON(retornoempresas), function(chave, valor) {

      $("input#cod").val(valor.COD);
      $("input#empresa").val(valor.EMPRESA);
      $("select#tributacao").val(valor.TRIBUTACAO);


    });


  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("Erro ao atualizar");
  }).always(function(retornoempresas) {
    console.log(retornoempresas);
  });
}
```

- Basicamente sempre utilizo esse padrão de programação.
- Minha dúvida talvez seja simples pra vocês, como eu faria esse mesmo processo no PHP utilizando PDO e como eu pegaria esses dados no retorno do AJAX (presumo que seja da mesma forma no AJAX).
- Minha dúvida é principalmente na parte do While no PHP.
- **Obrigado!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe muito mistério.

```php
//Abre a conexão
$PDO = db_connect();

//SQL para contar o total de registros
$sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users ORDER BY name ASC";

//SQL para selecionar os registros
$sql = "SELECT id, name, email, gender, birthdate FROM users ORDER BY name ASC";

//Conta o total de registros.
$stmt_count = $PDO->prepare($sql_count);
$stmt_count->execute();
$total = $stmt_count->fetchColumn();

//Seleciona os registros
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

//Lista os usuário
while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 echo $user['email'] 
}
```

Créditos: https://github.com/marciellioliveira/crud-php-pdo/blob/master/index.php

Comment: O fetchColumn do PDO se assemelha ao affected_rows do mysqli ?

Comment: O mysqli_affected_rows retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela operação anterior já o fetchColumn(1) em um select retorna o valor da coluna que você passa como parâmetro na função. Se o select retorna um valor como em `$sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users ORDER BY name ASC";` então ele retorna esse valor. Portnto comportamentos diferentes.

Comment: Beleza, Átila. Eu vi algo sobre isso aqui: $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). Isso não substituiria aquele While ali ?

Comment: Sim. é uma alternativa mais limpa

Comment: Mas tem exatamente a mesma função ?

Comment: Não. A diferença é que você não passa parâmetros. Use assim `$all = $stmt->fetchAll()`

Comment: Mas o $all vai ser um array ?

Comment: Sim. um array. cada elemento vai ser outro array com as propriedades de cada linha